# How can I show the audio duration and subtracting one second each second?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this function, I want every second audio duration to minus one but it returns NaN, Then I tried to delete `" : "` so it's fully numbers but `setInterval` is executed only once for example if audio duration is 0524 after clicking `.button` it only returns 0523.

```html
<button class="button"></button>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

```
var playng= new Audio();
playng.src = audio.mp3;
$('.button').click(function(){
    playng.play()
    songDur()
})
function songDur(){
    var audiod = playng.duration;
    var minutes = "0" + Math.floor(audiod / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(audiod - minutes * 60);
    var songTime = minutes + " : " + seconds;
    console.log(songTime);
    setInterval(function(){
    $('.demo').text(songTime - 1)},1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NaN` stands for "Not a Number" and two numbers with a colon in the middle is indeed not a number.

The reason why it only appears to run once if you remove the colon, is because you never update the value of `songTime`. You only set the text to `songTime -1`, but `songTime` is never updated so `songTime -1` will also always output the same number.

It is also worth mentioning that `setInterval` is not very accurate and can shift over time.

The best way to get a countdown timer that accurately counts down how much time is left in a song, is to subtract the `currentTime` from the `duration`. This will give you the seconds left so you can convert that into minutes and seconds. (Be sure to do the calculation *inside* the `setInterval` so it is recalculated for every interval.)

```js
var playng = new Audio();
playng.src = 'audio.mp3';
$('.button').click(function() {
  playng.play()
  songDur()
});

function songDur() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var timeRemaining = playng.duration - playng.currentTime;
    var minutes = Math.floor(timeRemaining / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeRemaining % 60);

    var secondsWithLeadingZero = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    $('.demo').text(minutes + ':' + secondsWithLeadingZero);
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Play</button>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qgp8k7bf/